# Sqlite3 with cygwin

Tags: c, sqlite, cygwin

How to install Sqlite3 with Cygwin? When I try to compile in Cygwin like this:

```
gcc -o basics basics.c
```

it says:

/tmp/ccpS4NGr.o:basics.c:(.text+0x67): undefined reference to `_sqlite3_open' /tmp/ccpS4NGr.o:basics.c:(.text+0x10b): undefined reference to`_sqlite3_exec' /tmp/ccpS4NGr.o:basics.c:(.text+0x172): undefined reference to `_sqlite3_exec' /tmp/ccpS4NGr.o:basics.c:(.text+0x1d9): undefined reference to`_sqlite3_exec' /tmp/ccpS4NGr.o:basics.c:(.text+0x243): undefined reference to `_sqlite3_prepare
_v2' /tmp/ccpS4NGr.o:basics.c:(.text+0x279): undefined reference to`_sqlite3_column_ count' /tmp/ccpS4NGr.o:basics.c:(.text+0x28f): undefined reference to `_sqlite3_step' /tmp/ccpS4NGr.o:basics.c:(.text+0x2cb): undefined reference to`_sqlite3_column_ text' /tmp/ccpS4NGr.o:basics.c:(.text+0x2ec): undefined reference to `_sqlite3_column_ name' /tmp/ccpS4NGr.o:basics.c:(.text+0x355): undefined reference to`_sqlite3_close' collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

***I kept the sqlite3.h in the same directory of basics.c along with 3 other files that comes with sqlite-amalgamation package***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you including it?

```
#include <sqlite.h>
```

or

```
#include "sqlite.h"
```

The latter form might well work; it'll check the current folder before the include path.

Comment: Thanks. Now I added like this #include "sqlite3.h" But now new problem arises. So I edit the question.

Comment: If the question has changed you should have created a new question.  Now the accepted answer is not useful to anyone because we don't know what the original question was.

Answer (score 2):

While you *can* build SQLite yourself, your don't have to.

Re-run Cygwin's `setup.exe`, and on the package selection screen, select the `libsqlite3-devel` package from the Libs category. Then your build command becomes:

```
gcc -o basics basics.c -lsqlite3
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to build and include the sqlite amalgamation!  Add that .c file to your command line:

```
gcc -o basics basics.c sqlite3.c
```

Comment: Can you write the command for example? Or how to install sqlite3? I want work it for cygwin.

Comment: @Mr. Flint - that's what the example there *is*.